# How can I convert a maven project to a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse that builds with Ant?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've got a java project that's using Maven in Eclipse, and would like to completely remove the Maven aspect of the project, and set it up as a completely stand alone Dynamic Web Project that doesn't depend on Maven at all, but uses Ant instead.

I assume this will involve:

- finding out the libs that are required
- creating an ant "build.xml" file
- more steps that I'm not sure of ;-)

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I usually use an Eclipse plugin called m2eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch it to use ant.  Maven comes with ant plugin.  Run mvn ant:ant and it will generate the build.xml for you.  This would make you dependent on ant though.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is install [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/) and [m2e-wtp](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/download/) in Eclipse.

Then make sure your Maven project is packaged as a .war.  See here for building a web app in Maven:

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/

Eclipse will see it as a Dynamic Web App with all the configuration and deployment capabilities.